# Does Sam's 'go-juice' make him physically stronger too?

Tags: supernatural

Episode 3, season 3 of Supernatural we see Sam being force-fed

> demon blood

In the bar, and opens a can of whoop-ass on the two hunters.

Is he physically stronger after taking his hit? Or is it just his determination at this point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not directly an effect of the demon blood, but it's not pure determination either.

The Supernatural Wikia lists the [powers given directly](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Sam_Winchester#Powers_and_skills) by the demon blood:

- Clairvoyance (manifesting as visions/premonitions)
- Telekinesis (after drinking Demon Blood, previously through heightened emotion and adrenaline)
- Clairsentience (manifesting as a "supernatural sense")
- Demon Exorcism (after drinking Demon Blood)
- Demon Destruction (after drinking large quantities of Demon Blood)
- Croatoan Virus Immunity
- Demonic White Light Immunity

There's a few other things to take note of, mentioned on that page and on [SupernaturalWiki.com](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Demon_Blood):

- Sam has a ruthless/careless side he rarely ever reveals - for example, when he's trying to stop the deal from taking Dean to hell.
- Demon blood is a drug.  Addiction and withdrawal symptoms included.
- Sam also acts more ruthless the more blood he's drunk.

It's not entirely certain whether or not it's the demon blood that makes him more ruthless, or simply unlocks part of his personality he'd rather not admit to.  Either way, one of the key effects of the blood is that it affects his ability to control himself.

Like other drugs, a dose will stop withdrawal symptoms, and the rush could easily make him feel like king of the world - willing to push his body to its limits and not giving a crap about his own well-being in the meantime.  Paired with making him more ruthless, well...

Comment: Excellent answer! It sounds like you're quite the supernatural buff. Check out my proposal, in meta, for supernatural, season 8 to be a topic of the week.

Comment: I think there's an element of supernatural strength provided by the demon blood. He decapitates Gordon Walker - a fellow hunter turned vampire - by pulling barbed wire tight around his throat (season 3, episode 7 - *Fresh Blood*). I don't think Sam would be physically capable of doing that normally.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Maaaybe, but remember that in-universe, regular hunters can also decapitate with one swing of a machete.

Comment: @Pureferret Already did =P

Comment: @Izkata I think there'd be a significant difference in the strength required to decapitate with a swing from a machete and the strength required to squeeze wire through somebody's neck. While there's some suspension of disbelief required to accept that hunters can sever in one swing *all the time*, it shouldn't be at all difficult to accept that they could on occasion do so.